# How to scan docker containers IPs from a docker container that is in the same network?

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

I am running multiple docker containers with docker-compose and all of them are in the same network.

Once the containers are up and running I would like to access from one of them to all the others through a shell script, where that script retrieves all IP addresses of the other containers from the docker network (first Ethernet interface eth0 inside the container).

I know there's a way to get IP addresses using container name, but I am running docker-compose with --scale flag so the script doesn't know how many containers are in that network, I am confused and don't know how to do that.

> The base image of all containers is ubuntu:20.04

Answer (score 0):

Since I couldn't find a simple way for now I created a script using **nmap** and **ifconfig**, it consists on getting the IP address of inet (Ethernet interface) from one of the docker machines then lookup on that network using nmap:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

EI=$(/sbin/ifconfig eth0 | grep inet | awk '{ print $2}') # Get inet IP of eth0
IPS=($(nmap $EI/24 | grep dindood | awk '{ print $6}' | sed 's/.$//; s/^.//')) # Look for the nodes Ip addresses
NAMES=($(nmap $EI/24 | grep dindood | awk '{ print $5}' | cut -f1 -d".")) # Look for the nodes Containers names
echo "host ip=$EI"

for i in "${!IPS[@]}"; do #loop through IP addresses found

    echo "hostname= ${NAMES[$i]} | IP= ${IPS[$i]}"

done
```

the output looked like this for me:

```sh
host ip=192.168.160.3
hostname= my_project_container_2 | IP= 192.168.160.2
hostname= my_project_container_1 | IP= 192.168.160.4
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to know how many instances of a particular service are running in scaled mode and need  to access them individiually? Isn't that something that should be taken care by a load balancer (with sticky sessions enabled if required) ?

Comment: I am actually working on a small [project](https://github.com/LQss11/dindood.git). where I create multiple docker containers as they are machines and install docker on each one of them, just needed that to play around ansible and docker swarm and maybe other things in the future, the thing is when I create a swarm in one of them I need to create a script that automatically SSH through all the other machines and uses the swarm token so I could create a swarm quickly in case I have like 10 20 containers (as nodes or workers...).

Comment: I know I could've worked with docker-machines but appears that they are [deprecated](https://docs.docker.com/machine/)